# Java script while loop stange behaviour in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Why does this:

```
i=0;
while(i<=4){
    console.log(i);
    i = i+1;
}
```

outputs: `0,1,2,3,4,5` but it should stop on the 5-th( `0,1,2,3,4` ) element not 6th(`5`)

PS: this happens if you paste the above code in google chrome console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 5 isn't in logged in the loop, but its the i variable.

```
i=0;
while(i<=4){
    console.log("log: " + i);
    i = i+1;
}
```

Comment: To clarify: The chrome console seems to `log` the last (global) variable assignment. Add a `foo = 'bar';` as the last line of (or even outside of) the loop, you'll see it display `0 1 2 3 4 5 "bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior under Chrome. It displays the last line evaluated. For instance, if you just enter: `i=5;` it will display `5` even though you didn't ask to display it through  `console.log`. In your example the last line evaluated is `i=i+1;` which, at this point, computes the `5` value.

Comment: Not quite correct. If the last line evaluated were a `var` in the `while` scope, that var wouldn't be shown. It seems to only show what happens on the "global scope".
Quick example: `var i=5; while(i--){var t=false;}` <-- Run that code in the console, then run: `var i=5; while(i--){t=false;}`

Comment: That's true, but even in this case it will display `undefined`. The point is, Chrome always tries to display something when you run a line into the console. Or you can cheat by calling something like `setTimeout(function(){i=0;
while(i<=4){
    console.log(i);
    i = i+1;
}},0);` but then it just displays the result (which is the setTimeout return value in this case) before your `console.log` calls instead of after.

Comment: I'm not disputing the fact chrome tries to display something, just that it can't necessarily display the last evaluated value.